# Erro no Relatório

Tags: genexus

nunca usei Genexus (desenvolvo em Java e Python), mas estou tendo que de dar manutenção a um sistema feito pelo meu pai.

Alterei um relatório que o sistema gera (apenas o título), fiz o "build all", depois copilei ...

Vi que ele coloca o executável na pasta "bin" - peguei essa pasta e enviei ao cliente, mas o relatório não muda. 
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Olá, AAG! Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Precisamos de mais informações do seu projeto, para podermos ajudar você. Com as informações que passou, fica difícil adivinhar a causa do seu problema.